# SQL server date conversion - 'Conversion failed'

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, casting, type-conversion

I have problem with converting date from `varchar` to `date` format:

`Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

I'm trying to convert/cast it like `SELECT convert(DATE, '25.02.2019');`. Can't change string order bacause the data are from existing table.

I know that the solution is easy but I'm still missing something and didn't get it yet :(

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. Just don't store or pass dates as strings. Use `date`-typed parameters and fields. If you want to parse data stored using the wrong type, use `CONVERT` or `PARSE` with the appropriate style number or format string

Comment: Using the wrong type can cause serious problems. For one, you can't use any indexes to speed up queries. The server will have to scan the entire table to find matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unable to fix the underlying problem (that the table uses the wrong data type), you need to apply the correct [`DATETIME` Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles), which for `dd.MM.yyyy` is 104:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '25.02.2019', 104);
```

If at all possible though you should correct the original table. You should **never** store dates using `VARCHAR`, there is not one good reason to do so, and lots of good reasons not to. It will save you a lot of headaches if you change your datatype to `DATE` and then you won't have to worry about conversion errors. The longer you leave it the worse it will get. If you can't change the table, have a word with your DBA, and tell them to change the table. If you don't have a DBA, find someone who can.

Some good articles on this below:

- [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

---

**ADDENDUM**

If you are unable to change the actual column because it is used by other processes, you can still sanitise the column by using a check contraint, and optionally include a computed column so you always have access to a real date, and not a varchar:

e.g.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#DateTest', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DateTest;

CREATE TABLE #DateTest 
(
        StringDate CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        RealDate AS CONVERT(DATE, StringDate, 104),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_DateTest__RealDate CHECK (TRY_CONVERT(DATE, StringDate, 104) IS NOT NULL)
);
```

This will allow you to continue to add/edit varchar dates:

```
-- insert valid date and check output
INSERT #DateTest (StringDate) VALUES ('25.02.2019');

SELECT RealDate
FROM #DateTest;
```

The check constraint will prevent you from adding any dates that are not dates:

```
--Try to insert invalid date
INSERT #DateTest (StringDate) VALUES ('29.02.2019');
```

This will throw an error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_DateTest__RealDate". The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.#DateTest___________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000704", column 'StringDate'.

You can even index the column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_DateTEst ON #DateTest (RealDate);
```

With the index on you can take advantage of the benefits storing dates properly gives.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know but when I tried using 104 format by 1st time it didn't work. I can't change colum data type because is some kind of user-customization varchar columns updated in external process.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is in the wrong format.

Should be:

```
SELECT convert(DATE, '2019-05-02')
```

Edit: If you can't get the date in that format, put 104 as a third argument.
Here's a list of the optional format arguments. https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. They shouldn't be stored or passed as strings in the first place